# Help setting document font size to 11pt?

Tags: fonts

I copied this latex files to produce a 11pt font summary but it would seem that there are additional comments in there that shrunk the size of the final pdf document. I am having a hard time trying to look for the commands that are responsible for it and I was hoping to get some help.

The only line of code that I can identify is `\tiny` but even after removing it and checking the font size they are still not size 11.

Is there a line of code to reset all settings and force it to be 11 pt ?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathstyle}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
% \usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment}

\ifthenelse{\lengthtest { \paperwidth = 11in}}
    { \geometry{top=.5in,left=.5in,right=.5in,bottom=.5in} }
    {\ifthenelse{ \lengthtest{ \paperwidth = 297mm}}
        {\geometry{top=0.4cm,left=0.4cm,right=0.4cm,bottom=0.4cm} }
        {\geometry{top=0.4cm,left=0.4cm,right=0.4cm,bottom=0.4cm} }
    }

%
% Table Settings
%

\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest { \paperwidth = 11in}}
    { \geometry{top=.5in,left=.5in,right=.5in,bottom=.5in} }
    {\ifthenelse{ \lengthtest{ \paperwidth = 297mm}}
        {\geometry{top=0.5cm,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm} }
        {\geometry{top=0.5cm,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,bottom=0.5cm} }
    }

\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]
{
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{} c @{}}
        #2
    \end{tabular}
}

% Turn off header and footer
\pagestyle{empty}

% Redefine section commands to use less space
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}%
                                {-1ex plus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
                                {0.5ex plus .2ex}%x
                                {\normalfont\tiny\bfseries}}
                                % {\normalfont\large\bfseries\sc}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0mm}%
                                {-1explus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
                                {0.5ex plus .2ex}%
                                {\normalfont\tiny\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0mm}%
                                {-1ex plus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
                                {1ex plus .2ex}%
                                {\normalfont\tiny\bfseries}}
\makeatother

% % Define BibTeX command
% \def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
%     T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

% Don't print section numbers
% \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.5ex}

%
% Custom Math Operators
%

\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rect}{rect}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tri}{tri}

\DeclareMathOperator{\bias}{bias}
\DeclareMathOperator{\se}{se}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mse}{MSE}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ar}{arg}

\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}\!}
\DeclareMathOperator{\EE}{\mathbb{E}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\V}{\mathbb{V}\!}
\DeclareMathOperator{\p}{\mathbb{P}\!}
\DeclareMathOperator{\pp}{\mathbb{P}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dd}{\mathrm{d}\!}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}

\newcommand{\pfrac}[2]{\left(\frac{#1}{#2}\right)}

% My definitions

\def\*#1{\mathbf{#1}}
\def\L{\mathcal{L}}
\def\N{\mathcal{N}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=10pt,topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex}

\def\labelitemi{--}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myalign*}{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{2pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{2pt}%
  \start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne
}%
{\endalign}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\raggedright
\footnotesize
\begin{multicols*}{5}

% multicol parameters
% These lengths are set only within the two main columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.25pt}
% \def\columseprulecolor{\color{myblue}}
\setlength{\premulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\postmulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2pt}

\begin{center}
     \small{\textbf{PCML Cheat Sheet}} \\
\end{center}

\tiny

\input{summary}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\footnotesize` is changing it.

Comment: Do you mean `\normalsize`?

Comment: there is also a `\tiny` just before `\input{summary}`.  you'll have to make a choice between a "compact" presentation and the 11pt size you say you want.

Comment: where did you copy this monster from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments which indicate misused commands `\mall`, `\footnote` and   `\tiny` in op text.

Answer (score 1):

`\footnotesize` at the line 135. You should comment or delete it.

And `\small{\textbf{PCML Cheat Sheet}}` at the line 148.